# How to remove Proceed to checkout button in cart page

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart, addtocart

I am working on mobile theme in Magento. When I add more than one product to cart proceed to checkout button showing twice both on top of the products and bottom of the products. How to remove from top?

Comment: You can find it in cart.phtml, remove <ul class="checkout-types top">

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in cart.phtml, remove `<ul class="checkout-types top">`